# xml Создание ripple на MaterialCardView

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" >
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:strokeColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >
            <TextView
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:id="@+id/tvTableNumber"
                app:MvxBind="Text Number; TextColor Status, Converter=TableStatusToTextColor;"/>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Добрый день. Мне нужно создать ripple на MaterialCardView, но как только ripple эффект появляется, самого клик ивента нет (должна открываться новая страница). Если я убираю данный эффект, новая страница открывается

Comment: На MaterialCardView ripple эффект появляется если просто вешаешь клик листенер, не нужны никакие android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground

Comment: Спасибо. Решено